# mpirun python serial parallel mix?

Tags: python, mpi

I am new to mpi4py package. I am running my code using this command. 
mpirun -np 4 python test.py  My task is to print "Hello World" 4 times but "do it only once" according to given sequential order in programme. How should i specify in my code so that next command should wait for completing of previous command.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

if rank==1:
   print 'do it only once',rank

sys.stdout.write(
"Hello, World! I am process %d of %d on %s.\n"
% (rank, size, name))


#MPI.Finalize()

if rank==2:
    print 'do it only once',rank
```

my answer is printing

```
Hello, World! I am process 2 of 4 on sas32.
do it only once 2
Hello, World! I am process 3 of 4 on sas32.
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 4 on sas32.
do it only once 1
Hello, World! I am process 1 of 4 on sas32.
```

but i want my answer this

```
  do it only once 1
  Hello, World! I am process 2 of 4 on sas32.
  Hello, World! I am process 3 of 4 on sas32.
  Hello, World! I am process 0 of 4 on sas32.
  Hello, World! I am process 1 of 4 on sas32.
  do it only once 2
```

Comment: You should only print from one rank. It is a trivial exercise in adding an `if` statement as you already have the code to obtain the rank.

Comment: I wanted to use MPI.Finalize() command at different interval so that next command should wait for completing the previous command. But when i am using more than once MPI.Finalize() i am getting this error. The MPI_Finalize() function was called after MPI_FINALIZE was invoked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [MPI_Barrier](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Barrier.html) to synchronize processes:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

if rank==1:
   print('do it only once %d'%rank)

MPI.COMM_WORLD.Barrier()
print("Hello, World! I am process %d of %d on %s."% (rank, size, name))
MPI.COMM_WORLD.Barrier()

if rank==2:
    print('do it only once %d'%rank)
```

output:

```
$ mpiexec -n 5 python mpibarrier.py 
do it only once 1
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 5 on abc.
Hello, World! I am process 2 of 5 on abc.
Hello, World! I am process 3 of 5 on abc.
Hello, World! I am process 4 of 5 on abc.
Hello, World! I am process 1 of 5 on abc.
do it only once 2
```

[MPI_finalize](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Finalize.html) will terminate your mpi session; you cannot call anything after finalize.